# python3 : The term 'python3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: screenshot of error]

> python3 : The term 'python3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please don't post code as image but as text. This is easier to read, to find and to copy.

Comment: Also, what's the actual question?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Make sure you add python to your **system path**

And try using **python** not **python3**

And try to run your code in  native command line of windows

Comment: I added the path to environment variables and tried with python instead of Python3!, It is working now! Thank you!

Comment: great replacing python3 with python solved my problem ) thank you )

Answer (score 6):

commands with python3 works for macOS/Linux. Use python for windows OS.

I ran into the same problem while creating a virtual environment for my project. Following instructions are quoted from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django

## macOS/Linux

sudo apt-get install python3-venv      # If needed

python3 -m venv env

## Windows

python -m venv env

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you installed the Python launcher when you installed Python, even without `python3` in your `PATH`, you should be able to launch Python with `py -2` (to use the most recent installed Python 2 version) or `py -3` (to use the most recent installed Python 3 version), thanks to [PEP 397: Python launcher for Windows](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/).

Answer (score 0):

Install python library by using "Run as administrator" and then try it again.

Trust me, I faced the same issue and it worked for me. Don't forget to check the "add python to path" option like in [this image](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ics.uci.edu%2F%7Epattis%2Fcommon%2Fhandouts%2Fpythoneclipsejava%2Fimages%2Fpython%2Fpythonsetup.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ics.uci.edu%2F%7Epattis%2Fcommon%2Fhandouts%2Fpythoneclipsejava%2Fpython.html&tbnid=vvIAALbYGBkRMM&vet=12ahUKEwjIqef0qYbzAhUINisKHRUMBw8QMygAegUIARCnAQ..i&docid=y2xQUv_TbZIIfM&w=666&h=410&q=python%20install%20screen&ved=2ahUKEwjIqef0qYbzAhUINisKHRUMBw8QMygAegUIARCnAQ).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the error by simply replacing python3 file.py with python file.py

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).