# Upgrade python version in virtualenviornment in visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I have a combination of this two questions on stackoverflow:
[How do I update a Python virtual environment with `venv` (in Python 3.3+) to use a newer version of Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58562928/how-do-i-update-a-python-virtual-environment-with-venv-in-python-3-3-to-use)

[python3 : The term 'python3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54023954/python3-the-term-python3-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet-function)

Currently, I have a virtual enviornment with the interpreter `python 3.7.0` in `visual studio code`  and I want to upgrade it to `python 3.9.0`. So for that I do the following line in the terminal (as mentioned in the first question):

```
python3.9 -m venv --upgrade
```

Then I am running in the error of the second question:

> PS C:\Users\admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Forecasts> python3.9 -m
> venv --upgrade python3.9 : The term 'python3.9' is not recognized as
> the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
> Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
> the path is  correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
>
> - python3.9 -m venv --upgrade
> - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (python3.9:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
> - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

what I am doing wrong here?

My python executers are stored in: `C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python3 : The term 'python3' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54023954/python3-the-term-python3-is-not-recognized-as-the-name-of-a-cmdlet-function)

Comment: When I list the question in my question, then it does not answer my question...

Comment: Does `py -3.9 -m venv --upgrade` work for you?  It sounds like you didn't add Python3.9 to PATH when you installed it which is why Python3.9 doesn't work.  In that case its likely that `py -3.9` won't work either, but worth checking.  Otherwise you need to update your PATH env variable or reinstall Python 3.9 and check the Add to PATH option.

Answer (score 2):

I have the following two versions of the python interpreter

| Version | Location |
| --- | --- |
| python3.7.9 | E:\Programs\Python\Python37 |
| python3.9.13 | E:\Programs\Python\Python39 |

1. Create a new **TESTENV** folder and use vscode to open it as a workspace.
2. Use the following command in the terminal to create a virtual environment named `testenv` (python version is ***3.7.9***)

   ```
   E:\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe -m venv testenv
   ```

   [image]
3. Use the following command to upgrade the enc virtual environment to pyton999

   ```
   E:\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe -m venv --upgrade E:\Desktop\TESTENV\testenv
   ```

   [image]

**So on your machine the command should look like this:**

```
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe -m venv --upgrade path\to\your\venv(python3.7.0)
```

*If the python version displayed in the **Select Interpreter** panel has not changed after executing the command, try restarting vscode or verify it with the code in the picture.*